# Arabic font not working in IE 11?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, arabic-support

i am facing issue for arabic font its working proper Mozilla and chrome nut not working proper in IE 11 my code is below anyone can you help me please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
           font-family: 'ArabicTwo_Bold';
           src: url('DroidKufi-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

                url('ArabicSans_Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
                url('DroidKufi-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('DroidKufi-Regular.svg#ArabicTwo_Bold') format('svg');
        }

        div , input {
         font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
        }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' value='account 1 2 3' />
        <div> account  1 2 3 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use `woff` also.

Comment: i used but not working

Comment: `div , input {
    font-family: 'ArabicTwo_Bold';
}` 
put this single `' '` or `" "` quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arabicsansbold';
    src: url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arabicsans_bold-webfont.svg#arabicsansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
                    body{
                font-family: 'arabicsansbold';
                        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">ArabicSans Bold     123456</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```